# css-grid renders divs in rows instead of columns

Tags: html, css, css-grid

[image]

I don't understand why it's rendered underneath instead aside (Create|Solve|Staticis div). The #left, #centre and #right div's are supposed to be on a one row displayed in 3 columns beneath eatch other.

How can i do this?
Thanks for your helP!
Here's my code:

```css
body {
  font: Helvetica;
  padding: 50px;
}

#gridoutter {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#gridoutter>div {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#gridinner>div {
  background-color: orange;
}

#gridinner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gridoutter">
    <div id="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    <div id="content">
      <div id="gridinner">
        <div id="left" class="partial">
          <h2>Create</h2>
          <p>Design your tests</p>
          <div id="centre" class="partial">
            <h2>Solve</h2>
            <p>Absolve your written tests</p>
          </div>
          <div id="right" class="partial">
            <h2>Statistcs</h2>
            <p>Track your progress</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="footer">
        FOOTER
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you didn't close your divs properly - see corrected version: https://jsfiddle.net/jwsnmx6y/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to close a div:

```css
body {
  font: Helvetica;
  padding: 50px;
}

#gridoutter {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 2fr 1fr;
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

#gridoutter>div {
  background-color: orangered;
}

#gridinner>div {
  background-color: orange;
}

#gridinner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>{{ title }}</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="gridoutter">
    <div id="header">
      HEADER
    </div>
    
    <div id="content">
      <div id="gridinner">
        <div id="left" class="partial">
          <h2>Create</h2>
          <p>Design your tests</p>
        </div><!-- Didn't close this div -->
        
        <div id="centre" class="partial">
          <h2>Solve</h2>
          <p>Absolve your written tests</p>
        </div>
        
        <div id="right" class="partial">
          <h2>Statistcs</h2>
          <p>Track your progress</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
      FOOTER
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```